# How to get past this error ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError, I need comments able to be posted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

This is in my Routes,

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 get 'comments/create'

 get 'comments/destroy'

 resources :posts do 
   resources :comments
 end
```

This is in my comments controller,

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
  def create 
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.save
    redirect_to @posts
  end

  def destroy 

  end
end
```

This is in my Posts.rb,

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :comments
end
```

and my html,

```
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>

<%= @post.text %>
  <h2>Comments</h2>

  <% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <p><%= comment.text %></p>
    <p><%= time_ago_in_words comment.created_at %> ago </p>
  <% end %>

  <%= form_for [@post, @post.comments.build] do |f| %>
    <p><%= f.text_area :text, :size => "40x10" %></p>
    <p><%= f.submit "Post Comment" %></p>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= link_to "Back", posts_path %>
    |
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post) %> 
    |
    <%= link_to "Delete", @post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [strong parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters), like this:

```
def create
  # ...
  @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
  # ...
end
# ...
private

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:text)
end
```

Comment: After doing this I get the following error "Cannot redirect to nil!"

Comment: @genobambino your `@posts` is `nil`, perhaps you meant `redirect_to @post`? Plus, this error is unrelated to my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see where its nil. Where are you seeing this?

Comment: @genobambino in `redirect_to @posts` line.

Comment: I don't understand how that is nil though, Also how would I even fix that?

Comment: @genobambino it's `nil` because you didn't set it. And I already wrote how you could fix this.

Comment: I'm so sorry about that, I haven't slept for a while so reading that was weird. You're answer was correct and I fixed it! Thank you so much! I also marked it as correct!